# Container not wrapping the content

Tags: html, css

I tried to contain the contents with in a container and am not able to do so! 
this is the code I used. I know their might be errors. What am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: none !important;
    width: 960px;
}

.rectangle {
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color:#67518e;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle"> 
  <div class="container">
    <a href="" style="float:left;color:white;">sample1</a>
    <a href="" style="float:right;color:white;">sample2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achive with this code.

Comment: i added the container so that the sample1 and sample2 links gets contained with in the width of 960px and not the edges of the page.

Comment: pls provide fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: cmon dude, when you get correct anwser please give point as "correct anwser" mark "✔". Please collecting points here so they can use them later !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I get what want to achive.

To wrap it and center horizontally (I assume you want to do it) you need to

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to .container

**NOTE:** there will not be any scroll horizontal because of `position: fixed;`

**TIP:** If you create css do tree of selectors in this case

```
.rectangle{}
```

and then

```
.rectangle .container{}
```

here is example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/myrqz29p/1/)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, if this is your solution for anwser please mark as "correct anwser" thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>sample</title>
    <style>
    .container {
        max-width: none !important;
        width: 960px;
    }
    
    .rectangle {
        min-height: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        height: 65px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
      //  right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color:#67518e;
    
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="rectangle">
                <a href="" style="float:left;color:white;">sample1</a>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="" style="float:right;color:white;">sample2</a>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```