# Div elements not positioning properly

Tags: html, css

I am using 2 `div` elements. These elements are overlapping each other, but I want them to follow one after another.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Online</title>
    <style>
    .rectangle {
     min-height: 40px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     height: 65px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border-radius: 0px;
     background-color:#67518e;
     z-index:15;
     
    }
    .section-content {
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        border-top: 1px solid green;
        border-bottom: 1px solid green;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0; 
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     background-color: yellow;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="rectangle"> 
     </div> 
    <div class="section-content">
    </div>
```

Comment: which div and how you want to make

Comment: What the hell, second same question in 1 hour? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776599/container-not-wrapping-the-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the positioning declarations, as this is causing your problems: (I have also removed some 'other' css that isn't used).

Since `Position:absolute;` will

> align itself to its nearest ancestor with a relative height

it is important to know that since you have the first div having a 'fixed' position, it will align itself to the top left of the page.

---

In order to make the divs "fill the width" of the page, I have included a "simple css reset", by including:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

in my css

---

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.rectangle {
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #67518e;
  width: 100%;
}
.section-content {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
</div>
<div class="section-content">
</div>
```

As a side note: I would like to highlight your use of

```
  min-height: 40px;
```

This won't ever be used as you are using a fixed height. This sort of styling only really comes into play when you're using the likes of percentages as units of measurement, and not px (since these won't dynamically change)

---

## [LIVE DEMO OF STICKY HEADER](http://jsfiddle.net/xxoj66gt/)

Comment: its working. But i want the divs to cover the left and rigt sides of the page completely.

Comment: just to fill the width of the page. @jbutler483

Comment: Its working good.I have one more doubt. I want the .rectangle to be fixed to the screen. Is it possible? @jbutler483:

Comment: is it poosible to keep the .rectangle fixed to the screen.

Comment: @SiddharthA: i've implemented a short, animated demo for a 'sticky header' (please note. it uses a *tiny* bit of jquery)

Comment: can u give me a link @jbutler483

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are using `position: fixed` to the element with class `.rectangle`. One solution without change position is to use `margin-top: 59px` to the element `.section-content`:

```css
.rectangle {
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #67518e;
  z-index: 15;
}
.section-content {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 59px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="section-content">
```

You can take a closer look to the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning) about the position.

Comment: what if O.P scrolls page that fixed div will hide page element

Comment: @sanojlawrence according to the OP _i want the elements to follow one after the other_.

Comment: without using fixed method any other method

Answer (score 0):

You could either make both `<div>`s `<span>`s, or to both CSS classes, you add the following line: `display: inline;`.